# I am working with Hibernate and I'm trying to add primary key in the table created by hibernate to store collection

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

The whole code worked before I wrote collectionID, but after that it created table named sequence-gen and it tries to add values(1)
Here's how my Entity looks like,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionId;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
public class Student {
    public int getStudent_id() {
        return student_id;
    }
    public void setStudent_id(int student_id) {
        this.student_id = student_id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getCGPA() {
        return CGPA;
    }
    public void setCGPA(float cGPA) {
        CGPA = cGPA;
    }
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int student_id;
    private String name;
    private float CGPA;
    /*
     * @Embedded private Address address;
     */
    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "Address",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
            )

    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence-gen", strategy = "sequence")
    @CollectionId(columns = { @Column(name="AddressTable_ID") }, generator = "sequence-gen", type = @Type(type="int"))
    private Collection<Address> listOfAddress=new ArrayList<Address>();
    public Collection<Address> getListOfAddress() {
        return listOfAddress;
    }
    public void setListOfAddress(Collection<Address> listOfAddress) {
        this.listOfAddress = listOfAddress;
    }
    /*
     * public Address getAddress() { return address; } public void
     * setAddress(Address address) { this.address = address; }
     */
}
```

And here's my clienttest looks like,

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
        SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
        // Inserting Data into table...
        Student s = new Student();
        //s.setStudent_id(2);
        s.setName("Yash");
        s.setCGPA(8.80f);
        Address address1=new Address();
        address1.setCity("Rajkot");
        address1.setPincode("360002");
        address1.setStreet("Sorathiyawadi");
        /* s.setAddress(address1); */
        Address address2=new Address();
        address2.setCity("Ahemdabad");
        address2.setPincode("380002");
        address2.setStreet("ISCON Mall");
        /* s.setAddress(address2); */
        HashSet<Address> sets=new HashSet<Address>();
        sets.add(address1);
        sets.add(address2);
        s.setListOfAddress(sets);
        //Transaction
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(s);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        s = null;
        // Retriving Information...
        Session s2 = sf.openSession();
        s2.beginTransaction();
        s = s2.get(Student.class, 1);
        System.out.println(s.getName());
    }

}
```

This is my model:

```
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String city;
    private String pincode;
    private String street;
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }
    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

}
```

And here is my config file:
    
    
    
        
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/yash
            root
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
            true
            create

What error i'm getting shows like...

```
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:19 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/yash]
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root}
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Tue Mar 31 08:19:20 IST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists Address
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@63884e4] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: drop table if exists sequence-gen
Hibernate: drop table if exists Student
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop table if exists sequence-gen" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table if exists sequence-gen" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-gen' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: create table Address (student_id integer not null, city varchar(255), pincode varchar(255), street varchar(255), AddressTable_ID integer not null, primary key (AddressTable_ID)) engine=MyISAM
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@6cd3ad8a] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table sequence-gen (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table sequence-gen (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table sequence-gen (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-gen (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: insert into sequence-gen values ( 1 )
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "insert into sequence-gen values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "insert into sequence-gen values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-gen values ( 1 )' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: create table Student (student_id integer not null, CGPA float not null, name varchar(255), primary key (student_id)) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: alter table Address add constraint FK4q6j38bhikrv1pjbmde52gg7 foreign key (student_id) references Student (student_id)
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Tue Mar 31 08:19:20 IST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into Student (CGPA, name, student_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from sequence-gen for update
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:21 AM org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1 execute
ERROR: could not read a hi value
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-gen for update' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentIdentifierBag.preInsert(PersistentIdentifierBag.java:406)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1311)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3202)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at Main.main(Main.java:36)

Mar 31, 2020 8:19:21 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Mar 31, 2020 8:19:21 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-gen for update' at line 1
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1356)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3202)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentIdentifierBag.preInsert(PersistentIdentifierBag.java:406)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1311)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-gen for update' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 1):

omit the "-" from "sequence-gen" and try it again